# TeamCity failing to import DotCover report

Tags: teamcity, dotcover

recently we upgraded teamcity to 2017.2, after that TC is failing to import the DotCover report file. I am trying to run XUNIT meta runner: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack/master/xUnit.net-dotCover/MRPP_xunit_dotcover.xml

and updated this parameter:
[string] $dotCoverExecutable = "%teamcity.tool.JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.bundled%"

command: write-host "##teamcity[importData type='dotNetCoverage' tool='dotcover' path='$outputFile']"

Error Message:
No available .NET Coverage report generator for type 'dotcover'. Skipped files: [D:\TCW\563efb8648d3acf2\xunitcoverage.dcvr]

i also tried generating HTML report and passed the html file to ##teamcity[importData , and getting this error:
No available .NET Coverage report generator for type 'dotcover'. Skipped files: [D:\TCW\563efb8648d3acf2\dotCoverReport.html]

Any help please?

Thanks,
Urivinty

Answer (score 1):

i am able to fix the issue by adding below line to MRPP Xunit meta runner. First we need to configure code coverage engine as documented here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Manually+Configuring+Reporting+Coverage

Write-Host "##teamcity[dotNetCoverage dotcover_home='$dotCoverExecutable']"